# Как сделать счётчик цикла While

Tags: python, tkinter

Здраствуйте, можете подсказать как сделать счётчик цикла While в Python.
Мне нужно сделать так что-бы это выводилось на экран спомощью tkinter,
проблема заключается в том что оно только 1 раз выводит переменную i.

Сам код:

```
import pyautogui as gui 
from time import sleep
import keyboard
from itertools import repeat
from tkinter import *
from threading import Thread

#Импорты

i= 0

#скрипт 
def script():        
    while True:
        global i
        i +=1
        gui.press("3")
        sleep( 9 )
        gui.keyDown("w") 
        sleep( 2 ) 
        gui.keyUp("w") 
        sleep ( 1 )
        print(i)
        
       


def okno():
    window = Tk()
    window.attributes("-topmost",True)
    window.title("Made In Wapid")  
    lbl = Label(window, text=(i), font=("Roboto Bold", 20))  
    lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)   
    window.mainloop()

th1 = Thread(target=okno).start()
th2 = Thread(target=script).start()
```

Comment: а функция внутри которой эта i сколько раз вызывается?...

Comment: Скорее всего не связано с проблемой, но сам код tkinter должен быть в основном потоке.

Comment: как его в основной поток засунуть?

Comment: Конечно, поздновато, но просто меняете `th1 = Thread(target=okno).start()` на вызов функции `okno()`, но делаете это после запуска th2.